# Adding sections to my mockup causes my aside to shift

Tags: css, html

I am trying to recreate the youtube video player page for a simple learner project I'm doing. At the moment I am just trying to divide up the page into sections/divs, changing the background colours, then getting them in the correct place on the page. I am using an `<iframe>` element for the main video section and an `<aside>` for the thumbnails/upnext section, this worked fine and I got them in place, however when I added two `<section>` elements below the iframe for comments etc, my aside jumps down the page. When I remove my section elements the aside goes back to where it's supposed to be, what am I doing that is causing this behaviour?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Embedded Video | Skip</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- NAV BAR -->
  <nav>

  </nav>

  <!-- WRAPPER -->
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="content">
      <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
      <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V74l_zS1x8E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <section>

      </section>
      <section>

      </section>
      <!-- SIDEBAR -->
      <aside>

      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;

}

#wrapper {

  width: 1440px;
  height: 1795px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#content {
  padding: 0 80px;

}

nav {
  background-color: gray;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

aside {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 415px;
  height: 1730px;
  float: right;
}

iframe {
  background-color: green;
  width: 855px;
  height: 480px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;

}

section {
  width: 855px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I'm not terribly familiar with the aside and section elements, I found that it seems the aside element is being "attached" to the element it precedes. If you move it up to between the first iframe and section, it renders as expected.

I'd upload a screenshot but my work network is being funny.

```
<iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V74l_zS1x8E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <aside>

  </aside>
  <section>

  </section>
  <section>

  </section>
```

Comment: Ah cool, thank you! I had no idea floated elements did that, I thought floating the aside right and the rest left would've been okay but obviously not. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Moved `aside` outside `#wrapper`.

padding added to `#wrapper` instead of `#content`.

Float and width added to `#content`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;

}

#wrapper {

  width: 1280px;
  height: 1795px;
  padding: 10px 80px 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

#content {
  float: left;
  width: 835px;
}

nav {
  background-color: gray;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

aside {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 415px;
  height: 1730px;
  float: right;
}

iframe {
  background-color: green;
  width: 855px;
  height: 480px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;

}

section {
  width: 855px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  </nav>

  <!-- WRAPPER -->
  <div id="wrapper">
<!-- CONTENT -->
<div id="content">
  <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
  <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V74l_zS1x8E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <section>

  </section>
  <section>

  </section>
  <!-- SIDEBAR -->
</div>
  <aside>

  </aside>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/t1920yf2/